# MarkerClusterer doesn't display icon in IE10

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-10, markerclusterer

If you view the following example http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html in IE10 - it shows the points but not the cluster icons.

Anyone know what the problem is / if there is a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue, you need to add the following code to inside the head section of the page to force the browser into IE9 mode

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

If you are displaying the map inside an IFRAME, then it must be added to the master page.

n.b. You will need to close and re-open your browser in order to see the map working correctly.

For more information see [this working example](http://www.logicrc.com/?map=UK).

Answer (score 2):

Forcing the browser into IE9 mode is bad practice - especially just because of MarkerClusterer. Instead modify the code on line 956 (https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js?r=110#956) from this:

```
if (document.all) {
    style.push('filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(' + 'sizingMethod=scale,src="' + this.url_ + '");');
} else {
    style.push('background:url(' + this.url_ + ');');
}
```

To this:

```
style.push('background:url(' + this.url_ + ');');
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another reason/fix for this issue. I was using an image for map markers which I was referring using javascript window.location.origin. Internet Explorer (IE) 10 or below versions don't have access to this object which was resulting in 'undefined' object for path.

Solution: Avoid using `window.location.origin` object. Use relative paths or following script:

```
if (!window.location.origin) {
      window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
    }
```

This script is not mine, I found it on internet. Hope this helps. Cheers